# Trying to perform kernel density analysis but obtain: 'error all input points identical' or 'error in executing grid expression'

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, error, kernel-density

I am trying to perform a density analysis of a point shapefile on ArcMap. I am unsure of what to insert for population field. I've tried the actual number of people in the census tract where my point is and also tried adding a column to insert count (of points), so that each point has a count of 1. I have also left it as None. Neither works.

I get 2 types of errors:

1. all input points are identical
2. errors in executing grid expression

Comment: I believe you should either be using the point density tool.  Either that or grid your map with a fishline, join points to the grids summing the points, and then run kernel density with the population field being the newly created count field in the joined layer.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I had to add a fishline, that was very helpful.